# Установить MySQL Connector/C на Ubuntu

Tags: c++, mysql, c, ubuntu

Как установить MySQL Connector/C на Ubuntu?

Выдаёт:

> fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Сообщение говорит что заголовочный файл `mysql.h` не найден - разберитесь с путями поиска заголовочных файлов. И еще проблемный код в вопросе не помешал бы.

Answer (score 1):

Установите `libmysqlclient-dev` - нужный заголовочный файл там. И посмотрите на пакеты с именами `libmysqlcppconn*` - возможно, нужный коннектор там есть.

Comment: почему то вообще не поставил никаких либ, в папке /usr/lib нет никаких упоминаний о mysql

Comment: Теперь вы знаете в какую сторону смотреть